# Animate.css causing black rects in Firefox

Tags: html, css, animate.css

I use animate.css to animate elements with markup like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/72hn2j1x/1/

```
<p class="animated fadeInUp">
   Long line Long line Long line Long line Long line Long
</p>
```

The problem is if I animate an element that takes more than one line of text, the rest of the line gets overlayed by a black rectangular when animation is in progress that disappears after the animation is finished. It happens in FF only (please see the jsfiddle attached).

Anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: Firefox 41.0.2 (MacOS and Windows) - I don't see that.

Comment: I use the same 41.0.2 with Windows 7 and I still have the issue. I should check it from home again.